# Need a hand with understanding this horribly written ActionScript

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm currently translating some ActionScript to C#. Most of the stuff is understandable and can be easily reproduced/improved while translating it to C#. I came over a utils class while following the flow of code, which provides basic functionalities. A lot of it is obsoloete, so I threw out most of the utility functions and replaced them with more proper methods already provided by the .NET framework.

Here an example:

```
// ActionScript
public static function encode(_arg1:String):String{
    var _local2:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    _local2.writeUTFBytes(_arg1);
    return (encodeByteArray(_local2));
}

// Corresponding C#
public static string encode(string _arg1) {
    return Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_arg1));
}
```

For clarity I just left the parameters names *as is*, though the naming is awful.
I am quite unfamiliar with C#-low-level stuff like enumerating through byte arrays and streams properly, because I'm usually not in touch with that part of C#. If I need some tool, I usually find it already implemented in .NET or search the web for great *snippets*.

I get a head ache with this function though. The namings are horrible:

```
private static const BASE64_CHARS:String = 
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

public static function encodeByteArray(_arg1:ByteArray):String{
    var _local3:Array;
    var _local5:uint;
    var _local6:uint;
    var _local7:uint;
    var _local2 = "";
    var _local4:Array = new Array(4);
    _arg1.position = 0;
    while (_arg1.bytesAvailable > 0) {
        _local3 = new Array();
        _local5 = 0;
        while ((((_local5 < 3)) && ((_arg1.bytesAvailable > 0)))) {
            _local3[_local5] = _arg1.readUnsignedByte();
            _local5++;
        };
        _local4[0] = ((_local3[0] & 252) >> 2);
        _local4[1] = (((_local3[0] & 3) << 4) | (_local3[1] >> 4));
        _local4[2] = (((_local3[1] & 15) << 2) | (_local3[2] >> 6));
        _local4[3] = (_local3[2] & 63);
        _local6 = _local3.length;
        while (_local6 < 3) {
            _local4[(_local6 + 1)] = 64;
            _local6++;
        };
        _local7 = 0;
        while (_local7 < _local4.length) {
            _local2 = (_local2 + BASE64_CHARS.charAt(_local4[_local7]));
            _local7++;
        };
    };
    return (_local2);
}
```

My guess is that this decodes data from `byte[]` into a Base64 string. If you paid attention you see that the first function I've mentioned uses this function. Is this one because of the mentioned C# implementation obsolete either? Or is my C# implementation wrong? If it I'd need a clue, not a whole implementation. :)

Here my last question: the author declared `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=` as Base64 chars. This is 65! Wikipedia tells me Base64 does not contain the character `=`. What if old data already has been encoded with that "wrong" char set? Would I need to decode it with the corresponding wrong, also badly written, decode method and encode it properly then with a .NET implementation?

Comment: recommend taking some of his existing data and what his current code produces to build a set of unit tests up that you can use to validate your implementation (assuming you can execute his action script) including something to capture this '=' question.

Comment: Humans can't write code like that. Must be some obfuscation tool.

Comment: @Mikeb: I have to admit that I've just guessed that this is ActionScript. I'm not familiar with the IDE of Adobe and just read and navigate through the code in Notepad++. I derive the meaning of the code from knowing a little JS.

Comment: @J0HN: I can't tell you whether or not the code I received was obfuscated and decompiled. I just got the code. Does this matter? Though my guess is, that the code might have been optimized (compression?). Obfuscated code, which can be read (mostly^^) by humans isn't really obfuscated, is it?

Comment: if you can call that readable - which I don't.

Comment: The function you are looking at is decompiled code here is a link to the original source http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/source/browse/trunk/as3crypto/src/com/hurlant/util/Base64.as Why do I get the feeling you are stealing someones app.

Comment: "This is 65!" no it's 0 based

Comment: @The_asMan: Regardless of being 0 based or not, it's count **is** 65.

Comment: @ebeeb with 0 based 64 bit you have access to 65. 0 is after all a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that whatever language this in treats _arg1 as a forward only read stream, this is taking 3 bytes at a time from the input string,

```
    while ((((_local5 < 3)) && ((_arg1.bytesAvailable > 0)))) {
        _local3[_local5] = _arg1.readUnsignedByte();
        _local5++;
    };
```

munging them up a bit into 4 'slots'

```
    _local4[0] = ((_local3[0] & 252) >> 2);
    _local4[1] = (((_local3[0] & 3) << 4) | (_local3[1] >> 4));
    _local4[2] = (((_local3[1] & 15) << 2) | (_local3[2] >> 6));
    _local4[3] = (_local3[2] & 63);
```

padding the 4 byte result out with '64' in case the 3 bytes came up short

```
    while (_local6 < 3) {
        _local4[(_local6 + 1)] = 64;
        _local6++;
    };
```

and then using the big string at the top as a pick array to choose the character to represent the munged bits

```
    while (_local7 < _local4.length) {
        _local2 = (_local2 + BASE64_CHARS.charAt(_local4[_local7]));
        _local7++;
    };
```

in js here : http://jsfiddle.net/H4f2p/

I ran `encodeByteArray('test')` and got back `dGVzdAAA`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this satisfying answer.